# Analytic vs algebraic proof

Tags: analysis, soft-question, terminology

I've ran into phrases like "this is a purely analytical/algebraic proof[...]" in a few books I've read, and I quite never got the full grasp of what the difference between one or the other might be.

Could someone give some examples of algebraic vs analytical proofs of some simple theorems for me to understand the difference? Thanks!

Comment: One wise-guy answer might be to say that if there are no epsilons and no inequalities in a proof, it’s algebraic. (But I don’t agree with this position.)

Comment: Fundamental theorem of algebra has complex analysis proof (analytic) and Galois theory proof (algebraic).